# could not find function "%n%"

Tags: r, dplyr

function "%n%" not working even though I've loaded package dplyr.

`mutate(category = ifelse(Year.Last.Used %n% c("2015", "2016"),"baseline","treatment"))`

Caused by error in `Year.Last.Used %n% c("2015", "2016")`:
! could not find function "%n%"

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 4):

I think that you probably want to use `%in%`..